# PC joystick doesn't work for Sekiro

Tags: pc, windows, sekiro-shadows-die-twice

I have Sekiro Shadows Die Twice on my PC. OS is windows 8.1. In game's setting there are 2 sections -- one for keyboard key binding and the other for joystick key binding.
I attached my joystick and when I wanted to play only the left analog worked. I know there's nothing wrong with the joystick because I've played games with it before. What should I do?
Does it need specific settings or program or something?
When I play with the keyboard sometimes I get so excited and press the wrong key and one little mistake in this game will kill you.

Comment: You sure the controller works perfectly? You should probably test it.

Comment: @Frank yeah i'm playing Samurai Warriors 4 with it on my pc.

Comment: Make sure that the joysyick is plugged into your PC before you launch the game. The game may not recognize a controller that is plugged in once it is already running.

Comment: @Despato i always do this before launching my games.

Comment: What "joystick" do you use? I have no problem using s PS3 controller on win 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified what controller you're using, try launching the game through Big Picture mode in Steam.

- Press the [Big Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Pb9.png) button on the top right of the Steam client

  [image]

Use your controller from now on

- Select "Library", find Sekiro
- Manage Game > Controller Options, make sure your controller is showing up there
- Go back
- Go to Controller Configuration > Browse Config > Community and try a few of those templates to see if it will force your other joystick to work

(It's hard to give specific answers when you didn't specify what hardware you use. Try to be as specific as possible.)

Sometimes all you need to do is just launch the game through Big Picture and Steam does some magic and everything works. It's how I get my Switch Pro controller to work without downloading any firmware.

Comment: In fact, if you can navigate the big picture mode with your controller, you can assume your controller is working through steam.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Steam platform? If so, there is a [small amount](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5199-TOKV-4426) of controllers officially supported. There are also some tips in this page how to make them work.

Comment: This is such a non answer. Sekiro is a Steamworks game, so it's only available on Steam, secondly every main controller is supported, and if it's not then you can force it to work with Steam controller emulation.